# Formula to find value between date ranges and then use the figure next to it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have developed a worksheet for my office work. I have also developed the formula that will be used in it. However, the formula is quite long and i want to be shortened.

Here is the detail for the formula.

```
=IF(
  AND(
    [Date]>=DATE(2014,7,1),
    [Date]<=DATE(2014,7,31),
    [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
  [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$3,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2014,8,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2014,8,31),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$4,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2014,9,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2014,9,30),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$5,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2014,10,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2014,10,31),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$6,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2014,11,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2014,11,30),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$7,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2014,12,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2014,12,31),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$8,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2015,1,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2015,1,31),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$9,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2015,2,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2015,2,28),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$10,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2015,3,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2015,3,31),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$11,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2015,4,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2015,4,30),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$12,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2015,5,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2015,5,31),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$13,
  IF(
    AND(
      [Date]>=DATE(2015,6,1),
      [Date]<=DATE(2015,6,30),
      [Description]="Diesel Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*'Tax Status'!$B$14,
  IF(
    AND([Description]="Furnace Oil"),
    [Value Ex. Sales Tax]*0.17,IF(AND([Description]="Lubricants"),[Value Ex. Sales Tax]*0.17,0)
  )))))))))))))
```

This formula is entered in my main table under header "Sales Tax".

This is my other table from where i am taking the tax rates.

```
Month   Tax Rate
Jul-14  17%
Aug-14  17%
Sep-14  17%
Oct-14  17%
Nov-14  17%
Dec-14  17%
Jan-15  22%
Feb-15  27%
Mar-15  37%
Apr-15  32%
May-15  34%
Jun-15
```

If there is anything unclear, please let me know so that I would make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, it's really a long formula, please describe shortly what it does. Also it would be very useful if you could post sample workbook to see the formula working.

Comment: This will calculate the Tax Amount in each month. The tax rate will be taken from the tax table.

Comment: Sorry if you think I'm too rude, but you'll hardly find anybody analyzing your couple of hundreds character long formula if you just give the description "calculate the tax amount" and posts only one of the input ranges. Please help us to understand your problem to be able to help.

Comment: Will it be possible to you if i send you the images of my file and then ellaborate the situation.

Comment: I think, it can be simplified, as `YEAR([Date])&MONTH([Date])` and use this in a `VLOOUP` to find matching `Tax Status`. Also, use [this site](http://excelformulabeautifier.com/) to make your formula more readable.

Comment: This is a community site where your question helps also others to learn, and not a personal support service, please post it here (of course change all data what can be confidential) and I'll have a look on it.

Comment: Also, you can only have 7 nested IF statements, and we have 12 months...

Comment: @zx8754, I had no idea that site existed.  Thanks!  Of course I found it after I manually edited the formula above :(.  I agree that this could be solved with a VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the date is actually formatted like that and not stored as text, this should work:

```
=IF(
    [Description] = "Diesel Oil",
    INDEX(
        TaxStatus!$B:$B,
        MATCH(
            DATE(
                YEAR(
                    [Date]
                ),
                MONTH(
                    [Date]
                ),
                1
            ),
            TaxStatus!$A:$A,
            0
        )
    ) * [ValueEx.SalesTax],
    IF(
        OR(
            [Description] = "Furnace Oil",
            [Description] = "Lubricants"
        ),
        [ValueEx.SalesTax] * 0.17,
        0
    )
)
```

(Edited to add the final two criteria to the end and to fix a couple of errors.)